# how to calculate the time different in matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to calculate the different between to time in the second

I have this code

```
a=['07:00:00'; '07:15:00'; '07:30:00'];

add = [60; 85; 136];

sec_per_day = 24*60*60;

Result = datestr(datenum(a, 'HH:MM:SS') + add/sec_per_day, 'HH:MM:SS')

Result =

07:01:00

07:16:25

07:32:16
```

**Now** I want to calculate the time different in a second between first result and the second result (example: between 07:32:16 and 07:16:25)?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
a=['07:00:00'; '07:15:00'; '07:30:00'];
add = [60; 85; 136];
sec_per_day = 24*60*60;
[~,~,~,~,m,s] = datevec(datenum(a, 'HH:MM:SS') + add/sec_per_day);
min_to_sec = m*60;

min_to_sec = 60
             960
             1920

s = 0
    25
    16
```

To check the difference between 3 and 2

```
time_difference = (min_to_sec(3)+s(3)) - (min_to_sec(2)+s(2));
time_difference = 951
```

Does this answer your problem?